# How to configure browserify for different library directories

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, browserify

I am trying to convert my project from require.js to browserify.

In the browserify demos [here](http://browserify.org/demos.html) there is no spefic directory defined. When I try to do it like that:

```
var select2 = require('select2');
```

I get this error:

```
angular.js:11655 Error: Module name "select2.js" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

Is there a configuration file for browserify to define library directories or something similar?